# Ordered list not incrementing properly

Tags: html, css, html-lists

Within this ordered list, I'm trying to use decimal numbers but for some reason it is not numbering as expected. What needs to be done in order to fix the numbering for sections B & C and achieve the following?:

2) B

2.1) B1

2.2) B2

2.3) B3

3) C

```css
ol {
 counter-reset: item;
 list-style-type: decimal;
}
li {
 display: block;
}
li:before {
content: counters(item, ".") ") "; counter-increment: item
}
<!-- begin snippet: js hide: false console: true babel: false -->
```

```html
<ol>
  <li><a>A</a>
  </li>
  <ol>
    <li><a>A1</a>
    </li>
    <li><a>A2</a>
    </li>
    <li><a>A3</a>
    </li>
    <li><a>A4</a>
    </li>
  </ol>
  <li><a>B</a></li>
  <ol>
    <li><a>B1</a>
    </li>
    <li><a>B2</a>
    </li>
    <li><a>B3</a>
    </li>
  </ol>
  <li><a>C</a>
  </li>
</ol>
```

```
content: counters(item, ".") ". "; counter-increment: item
}
```

```html
      <ol>
        <li><a>A</a></li>
        <ol>
          <li><a>A1</a></li>
          <li><a>A2</a></li>
          <li><a>A3</a></li>
          <li><a>A4</a></li>
        </ol>
        <li><a>B</a></li>
        <ol>
          <li><a>B1</a></li>
          <li><a>B2</a></li>
          <li><a>B3</a></li>
        </ol><li><a>C</a></li>
        </ol>
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The sub-`ol`s need to be inside the `li` elements:

```css
ol {
  counter-reset: item;
  list-style-type: decimal;
}
li {
  display: block;
}
li::before {
  content: counters(item, ".")") ";
  counter-increment: item
}
```

```html
<ol>
  <li>
    <a>A</a>
    <ol>
      <li><a>A1</a>
      </li>
      <li><a>A2</a>
      </li>
      <li><a>A3</a>
      </li>
      <li><a>A4</a>
      </li>
    </ol>
  </li>
  <li>
    <a>B</a>
    <ol>
      <li><a>B1</a>
      </li>
      <li><a>B2</a>
      </li>
      <li><a>B3</a>
      </li>
    </ol>
  </li>
  <li>
    <a>C</a>
  </li>
</ol>
```